# .net core Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity with Windows authentication

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-core, asp.net-identity, windows-authentication

I have a .net core 3.1 mvc application with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity managed accounts. Application is running under IIS in **intranet**.
There are two possible options in order to authenticate:

1. **Standard** - if client use "username and password" from **Identity tables**.
2. **Domain** - if client use "username and password" from domain Active Directory. (App queries Active directory to verify if such user exist - if yes -> all data about the account is automatically copied to **Identity tables**.

In both scenarios - client needs to enter username and password

I would like to let domain users to pass authorization without entering a username and password. They are already logged in into PC with domain user/pass.

If it's not possible - is there any option to set mvc core application for both Windows authorization and individual user accounts?